# Java - SimpleDateFormat wrong format

Tags: java, postgresql, jsf

In my Postgresql database, I have a timestamp without time zone with this value : `"2012-06-15 17:49:46.423"` (default datatype used by Hibernate).

If I format with SimpleDateFormat and this pattern `"EEEE dd MMMM yyyy"`,  SimpleDateFormat#format returns "jeudi 14 juin 2012".

Why the result is not "vendredi 15 juin 2012" ?

French to English translation for non-french spoken :

```
"jeudi 14 juin 2012"    => "Thursday 14th of June 2012"
"vendredi 15 juin 2012" => "Friday 15th of June 2012"
```

**Hibernate 3.6.8.Final**
**JSF 2.0**
**JBoss 5.1.0.GA**
**Java 6**

Thanks.

Comment: Timezone of the machine that is producing this result?

Comment: GMT +1 (JBoss side) , GMT +0200 (Postgresql)

Comment: Also "jeudi" is "Thursday", not "Tuesday."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching, it turns out that I had two main options. Either I set the time zone through Hibernate or JSF.

**Option 1 : Hibernate**
I could change access type to Property. So in the setter, I would adjust the timestamp value to the right time zone. Another solution would be to create a custom Hibernate User Type.

Full details with code here : [Mapping Dates and Time Zones with Hibernate, Part 2: Few Solutions](http://dev-metal.blogspot.fr/2010/12/mapping-dates-and-time-zones-with.html)

**Option 2 : JSF**
Last option, I either create a `custom converter` in JSF or more simply, I use the *timeZone* attribute of `f:convertDateTime`.

This how I did it :

```
<h:outputText value="#{row.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="EEEE dd MMMM yyyy" locale="fr_FR" type="date" timeZone="Europe/Paris" />
</h:outputText>
```

All my dates are correct now !

Source (in french) : [Comment utiliser le timezone du compensant JSF convertDateTime](http://everythingiswrong.free.fr/index.php/2010/09/10/comment-utiliser-le-timezone-du-compensant-jsf-convertdatetime/)

Answer (score 1):

It's showing you just one day ahead of what you expect. Reason might be server time which is on another time zone I guess. Anyways the below code is working fine:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.FRENCH);
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy zzzz G", Locale.FRENCH);
```

try this

also printing out a date will automatically print formatted date text in machine time zone.